# jquery ajax online support chat

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, chat

Is there any FREE script available for online customer support in AJAX, JQUERY , php

like person have own window to chat ...

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here are some written with PHP and JavaScript (not necessarily jQuery):

- [Micro Chat](http://www.hotscripts.com/listing/micro-chat/)
- [BlaB! Lite](http://www.hotscripts.com/listing/blab-lite/)
- [PHP Chat](http://www.hotscripts.com/listing/php-chat/)
- [Free PHP Ajax Chat Super](http://www.hotscripts.com/listing/alilg-php-ajax-chat-free/)

Specifically jQuery:

- [Gmail/Facebook Style jQuery Chat](http://anantgarg.com/2009/05/13/gmail-facebook-style-jquery-chat/)
- [Building a jQuery/PHP Powered Chat](http://css-tricks.com/jquery-php-chat/)
- [Free PHP Chat Script + Tutorial](http://www.webstockbox.com/php/free-php-chat-script-tutorial/)

There's also a list of 279 PHP chat scripts [here](http://www.hotscripts.com/category/php/scripts-programs/chat-scripts/), a lot of which seem commercial but some are free.

If you browse enough, I'm sure you can find one to suit your needs.

Comment: An updated and mobile ready version is available here: http://www.livesupportrhino.com

Comment: for Gmail/Facebook Style jQuery Chat, how to get available user, Sir?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for one to one chat, [CometChat](http://www.cometchat.com/) looks promising.