# How to add a live chat to a web page as a support service

Tags: javascript, php, html, chat

I have been trying to research this with no joy and I have no idea where to start but can somebody give me some idea as to how to add a live chat to my page for customer support?

I'm guessing its PHP but can't find anything so can't work it out.

Thanks

I ask my first ever question on here and I get banned!!! If I made a mistake why not just tell me instead of people voting me down and banning me from asking questions?! is there no scope for anybody to learn how things work on this site?! Simple Terrible way to treat people

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621568/jquery-ajax-online-support-chat) seems a reasonable place to start.

Comment: I'm afraid "how to implement a chat system" is a bit too broad for a Stack Overflow question.  We'll be happy to help with any specific questions you have in your implementation, but as it stands this question doesn't really have a meaningful answer.

Comment: There are third party chat clients available (many are free of cost). Installation instructions are also given in them. May be you can look for those.

Comment: how do i get the ban lifted on me asking questions? this is crazy!

Comment: Its not crazy, the system (not other users) has decided that the quality of your questions is consistently low.  And its not your first question .... you have 7 in your profile.  And there's nothing that we as other users can do - you need to edit your questions to improve them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could start looking at the jabber compatible open fire chat server at http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/

It has a bosh plugin to enable it to chat over the web.

The client examples can be found at
https://code.google.com/p/xmpphp/ (Assuming you are using PHP)